# weird characters in username

Tags: windows-7, special-characters

My cousin used weirds characters in his username like  , may it cause some problem in future? Because that character is in path.

> C:/Users/Jake/

Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate

Comment: If it works now, it should work in the future. :)

Answer (score 4):

Windows NT can handle any Unicode character in file names; if anything breaks, it would only be individual poorly-written programs. In case of problems, it's possible to rename the profile directory and then adjust the registry. (The directory name and the user name do *not* always need to be the same.)

User names support full Unicode as well, but they aren't actually used by the system (SIDs are), so there shouldn't be any problem with such a username at all, and it can be renamed very easily. (Aside from occassions where you have to *enter* the username, for example, network logons... but one can copy/paste.)

Comment: But there is, there are NSIS errors.

Comment: Then NSIS isn't written to handle this properly (which surprises me!)